# How to use Ansible 2.9.2 python API to execute tasks?

Tags: python-3.x, ansible, ansible-api

I am using Ansbile 2.9.2 python API and python 3.7.2 to get crontab information from servers in hosts file.

I look through the [Ansible API document](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_api.html), but the sample code only works for 'localhost'.

here is my code api.py

```
# !/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

import django
import environ
import os
import re
import sys
from ansible import context
from ansible.executor.task_queue_manager import TaskQueueManager
from ansible.inventory.manager import InventoryManager
from ansible.module_utils.common.collections import ImmutableDict
from ansible.parsing.dataloader import DataLoader
from ansible.playbook.play import Play
from ansible.plugins.callback import CallbackBase
from ansible.vars.manager import VariableManager
from configurations import importer

project_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
sys.path.append(project_path)  # 将项目路径添加到系统搜寻路径当中

env = environ.Env()
read_env_file = env.bool("DJANGO_READ_DOT_ENV_FILE", default=True)
if read_env_file:  # OS environment variables take precedence over variables from .env
    env.read_env(os.path.join(project_path, ".env"))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", env("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"))
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION", env("DJANGO_CONFIGURATION"))

importer.install()
django.setup()

from django.conf import settings
from godie.imt.models import IMTInfo
from godie.utils.common import DEP_ENV, app_path


class ResultCallback(CallbackBase):
    """A sample callback plugin used for performing an action as results come in

    If you want to collect all results into a single object for processing at
    the end of the execution, look into utilizing the ``json`` callback plugin
    or writing your own custom callback plugin
    """

    def v2_runner_on_ok(self, result, **kwargs):
        """Print a json representation of the result
        This method could store the result in an instance attribute for retrieval later
        """
        print(result)

        imt_id = int(variable_manager.get_vars(host=result._host).get("imt_id"))
        main_ip, dep_env = str(result._host), None
        # 获取字典格式的输出结果
        stdout, stderr = result._result.get("stdout_lines", ""), result._result.get("stderr_lines", "")
        text = stdout if stdout else stderr  # Tasks中的一个dict(即一条Ansible命令)，不会同时输出stout和stderr
        print(text)
        try:
            imt = IMTInfo.objects  # 定义IMTInfo对象管理器
            if re.search("cd /home/imt", str(text)):
                print(main_ip + "Crontab:\n" + str(text))
                imt.update_or_create(id=imt_id, defaults={'crontab': str(text), 'status': '2'})
            if re.search("dep.admin.environmentID=", str(text)):  # True表示获取DEP-IMT连接信息成功
                dep_env = re.compile(r"=").split(text[0])[1]
                print(main_ip + " DEP环境: " + dep_env)
                imt.update_or_create(id=imt_id, defaults={'dep_env': DEP_ENV.get(dep_env, '0'), 'status': '3'})
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            settings.DB_LOG.exception(f"imtinfo.py- IMTInfo表更新失败，main_ip:{main_ip} 报错内容:\n{e}")


# since the API is constructed for CLI it expects certain options to always be set in the context object
context.CLIARGS = ImmutableDict(connection='smart', module_path=None, forks=4, become=None, become_method=None, become_user=None,
                                check=False, diff=False)

# 用来加载解析yaml文件或JSON内容,并且支持vault的解密
loader = DataLoader()  # Takes care of finding and reading yaml, json and ini files
passwords = dict(vault_pass=None)  # become_user的密码

# Instantiate our ResultCallback for handling results as they come in. Ansible expects this to be one of its main display outlets
results_callback = ResultCallback()

# create inventory, use path to host config file as source or hosts in a comma separated string
inventory = InventoryManager(loader=loader, sources=f"{app_path}/ansible/hosts")  # 主机清单的路径

# variable manager takes care of merging all the different sources to give you a unified view of variables available in each context
variable_manager = VariableManager(loader=loader, inventory=inventory)

# create data structure that represents our play, including tasks, this is basically what our YAML loader does internally.
play_source = dict(
    name="Get IMT information",
    hosts="all",  # 传入hosts分组或main_ip
    gather_facts="no",
    tasks=[
        dict(action=dict(module='shell', args='ls'), register='shell_out'),
        # {{ file }}是在Inventory中定义好的变量
        # dict(name='crontab', action=dict(module='shell', args='crontab -l'), register='shell_out'),  # 获取IMT的Crontab信息
        # dict(name='dep_env', action=dict(module='shell', args='cat {{ file }} | grep ^dep.admin.environmentID'), register='shell_out'),
        dict(action=dict(module='debug', args=dict(msg='{{shell_out.stdout}}')))  # Print statements during execution
    ]
)

# Create play object, playbook objects use .load instead of init or new methods,
# this will also automatically create the task objects from the info provided in play_source
play = Play().load(play_source, variable_manager=variable_manager, loader=loader)

# Run it - instantiate task queue manager, which takes care of forking and setting up all objects to iterate over host list and tasks
tqm = None
try:
    tqm = TaskQueueManager(
        inventory=inventory,
        variable_manager=variable_manager,
        loader=loader,
        passwords=passwords,
        stdout_callback=results_callback,  # Use our custom callback instead of the ``default`` callback plugin, which prints to stdout
    )
    result = tqm.run(play)  # most interesting data for a play is actually sent to the callback's methods
finally:
    # we always need to cleanup child procs and the structures we use to communicate with them
    if tqm is not None:
        tqm.cleanup()
```

and the **hosts** file

```
[PTPS]
172.17.193.162 ansible_user=imt ansible_ssh_pass=*****
```

when `python3 api.py` executed, NOTHING happened, no printed information.

Does anyone know where I am wrong?  Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your should probably use Ansible Runner for this, the Ansible Python API that you're interfacing with has no promise of backwards compatibility.

https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io

Answer (score 0):

Faced similar problem. To see errors try to remove:

```
stdout_callback=results_callback
```

Also add to **hosts** file:

```
ansible_connection=ssh
```